# DataTables sorting by time and number value

Tags: jquery, sorting, datatables, tablesorter

I have created and initialized a table using DataTables like this

```
var tablePayouts = $('#TabelaA').DataTable({
    ajax: {
        "url": "/Home/GetTableA",
        "type": "POST",
        "dataSrc": ""
    },
    columns: [
        {
            "data": "gm_Company_No",
            title: "Company",
            orderable: false
        },
        {
            "data": "amount",
            title: "Amount",
            orderable: false
        },
        {
            "data": "timestamp",
            title: "Time",
            orderable: false,
            render: function (time) { 
                return moment(time).format("HH:mm:ss")
            }
        },
        {
            "data": "request",
            visible: false,
            orderable: false
        },
    ],
    createdRow: function (row, data, dataIndex) {
        $(row).attr("data-id", data["id"]);
        $(row).attr("data-allow", data["allow"]);
        $(row).attr("data-req", data["request"]);
    },
    order: [[2, "desc"]]
});
```

I need my table to show the most recent entries, which I have done using `order: [[2, "desc"]]` for the Time column. The thing I can't wrap my head around is how to (after sorting by time) put all rows where the request is 0 to the bottom of the table. Sorting based on request value is not needed anywhere else.
The possible values that can appear in the request column are 0, 1, 2, 3.
I have tried sorting by `[[2, "desc"], [3, "desc"]]` but then it seems that sorting by time is priority and rows with request value 0 ends up somewhere in between. Vice versa also doesn't work, it messes up time sorting.

Thanks.

Comment: A simple solution would be to add an extra column. Let's call it "Priority". If request = 0 then priority = 0. All other rows will have a priority of 1. Now you can sort by priority first, then by time, then by amount. Other solutions are possible - but they will probably tend to make sorting less intuitive for users. You can provide "priority" as part of the source data, or you can derive it on-the-fly in your table using a DataTables columndef function.

Comment: That's really clever and worked. Thanks!